# Template for custom post with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

The theme that I'm developing is basically a portfolio, where the projects are custom post type and they are divided in categories (custom taxonomies). Here is how I'm defining both:

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('My Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Portfolio Item', 'add new portfolio item'),
    'edit_item' => _x('Edit Portfolio Item', 'edit portfolio item'),
    'new_item' => _x('New Portfolio Item', 'new portfolio item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
    'not_found' => __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => null,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array(null)
);
register_post_type('portfolio', $args);

register_taxonomy('project_category', array('portfolio'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => "Project Categories",
    'singular_label' => "Project Category",
    'rewrite' => true
));
```

So in the homepage I'm listing all terms for the tax. "project_category" and I want a template file for a single term (for example, "jQuery Plugins" or "WordPress Themes") where I can list all project with that term.

I looked in the WP template hierarchy and I believe the template that I need is

```
taxonomy-$taxonomy.php
```

My file is named taxonomy-project_category.php and it doesn't find it. I also tried with taxonomy.php, term.php, archive.php ... no success. I think the problem is with the links:

```
<a href="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
```

Any ideas? 
Cheers

Comment: What happens if you go to `www.yoursite.com?product_category=jquery-plugins`? And what do you mean doesn't find it? Doesn't find the template or doesn't find the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the OPs answer that the problem was not to do with the template, but using an incorrect url.

To get the link of a taxonomy term you can use [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link):

```
  <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term,'product_category')?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy templates support  `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{slug}.php`  so have you tried:

```
taxonomy-project_category-jquery-plugins.php  
// for the term Jquery Plugins, please alter to actually match what your term slug is
```

That name format looks a little weird, you might want to consider using `project-category` instead.

Also turn on [debugging](http://debugggg.files.wordpress.com) and install the debug bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, I'm posting this just in case anyone finds this question.

The problem was in the link, this is how it should look like:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/project_category/' . $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
```